# fprintf() in C makes garbage filename when called via Java Native Interface

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I'm doing a Java program that calls some C functions via the JNI. I have a situation where I gather a bunch of computer energy readings in C and want to write them to a file. Ideally, I want to use `fprintf()`, instead of formatting all the data as a string, passing it up to Java through the JNI interface, and then writing it to file the Java way, but that seems a lot less efficient.

The only problem is that when I do `fprintf()` in C, the output file I get has a garbage name. Definitely not the file name I provided it.

```
alejandro@alejandro-ThinkPad-E15:~/throwawayfiles$ ls
''$'\360\210\025\032\a'
```

The contents of the file are what I expect it to be, though. I've also called this function in C and it worked just fine, the only problem is when I facilitate calling it from a Java program. Is there a way that I can make sure that the output file has the name I actually want? Or is this just one of the problems of JNI stuff that I have to deal with. Like I said, plan B is to put all the data in a String, send it to java, and filewrite from there, but that's slow, and also code I'd rather not write :)

Thank you!

The code used to write to file. I'm handling a data structure AsyncEnergyMonitor that gathers energy readings. All of the reading and data storage is done in C, but it's all faciliated in the larger context of a Java program.

```
private native static void writeToFileFromC(String filePath);

public void writeToFile(String filePath)
{
    writeToFileFromC(filePath);
}
```

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_jrapl_AsyncEnergyMonitorCSide_writeToFileFromC(JNIEnv* env,
  jclass jcls, const char* filepath)
{
    writeToFile(monitor, filepath);
}
```

Here is where the file is initially opened and I write in the header line.

```
void writeToFile(AsyncEnergyMonitor *monitor, const char* filepath){
    FILE * outfile = (filepath) ? fopen(filepath,"w") : stdout;

    fprintf(outfile,"samplingRate: %d milliseconds\n",monitor->samplingRate);
    fprintf(outfile,"socket,dram,gpu,core,pkg,timestamp(usec since epoch)\n");
        
    if (USING_DYNAMIC_ARRAY)
        writeToFile_DynamicArray(outfile, monitor->samples_dynarr);
    if (USING_LINKED_LIST)
        writeToFile_LinkedList(outfile, monitor->samples_linklist);

    if (filepath) fclose(outfile);
}
```

And here are the two functions I use to write the rest of the data, depending on whether the data is stored in a linked list or a dynamic array.

```
void
writeToFile_DynamicArray(FILE* outfile, DynamicArray* a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a->nItems; i++) {
        EnergyStats current = a->items[i];
        char csv_string[512];
        energy_stats_csv_string(current, csv_string);
        fprintf(outfile,"%s\n",csv_string);
    }   
}
void
writeToFile_LinkedList(FILE* outfile, LinkedList* l) {
    LinkNode* current = l->head;
    while(current != NULL) {
        int upperbound = (current == l->tail) ?
            (l->nItemsAtTail) : (NODE_CAPACITY);
        for (int i = 0; i < upperbound; i++) {
            char ener_string[512];
            energy_stats_csv_string(current->items[i], ener_string);
            fprintf(outfile,"%s\n",ener_string);
        }
        current = current->next;
    }   
}
```

Comment: It work help if you showed the code used to open the file.

Comment: `Java_jrapl_AsyncEnergyMonitorCSide_writeToFileFromC(JNIEnv* env, jclass jcls, const char* filepath)`?!?!?!  **Where** are you getting a JNI function that you think is going to get passed a `const char *` that can be used directly in C code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to explicitly convert the filepath name from a Java string to a C string. Had nothing to do with file writing from C. Just made a garbage string name because I didn't convert

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_jrapl_AsyncEnergyMonitorCSide_writeToFileFromC(JNIEnv* env,
  jclass jcls, const char* filepath)
{
    writeToFile(monitor, filepath);
}
```

Fixed it to

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_jrapl_AsyncEnergyMonitorCSide_writeToFileFromC(JNIEnv* env, jclass jcls, 
  jstring jstringFilepath)
{
    const char* filepath = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jstringFilepath, NULL);
    writeToFile(monitor, filepath);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jstringFilepath, filepath);
}
```

All good now.